# Release pipeline: Select different branch for Azure Repos Git artifact

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

Have a release that uses a reference to a configuration-type repo.

[image: **enter image description here**]

When I configure, I can set the "Default" branch to master:

[image]

When I create a release, I can chose a branch for the main build artifact:

[image]

But I cannot chose the branch of the Git repo, it is fixed on master and no Branch Version Picker is available:

[image]

Do I have to create an entire new pipeline to release a different branch of this artifact?
What `Default` means in the context of the configuration, then?

Thank you -

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the option is available when configuring the source, you can set the Default Version to be `Specify at release time`

[image]

Unfortunately this does not work when there is a trigger on build-artifact

[image]

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/379296/cannot-have-default-version-type-selectduringrelea.html